# How to add a class to a container div ONLY IF an image has a class of .landscape?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Using jQuery I'd like to be able to add a new class to the container div (.figure-left) only if the image within it has a class of .landscape**

I'm using a great script I found on [CSSnewbie.com](http://www.cssnewbie.com/how-to-create-simple-stylish-and-swappable-image-captions/comment-page-2) that uses the Alt tag of an image as a caption - very useful when the CMS I'm using doesn't support image captioning.

I have the *basic* script working and I've styled the CSS so the layout won't break if Javascript is turned off. The bit I can't get to work is my 'addition' :)

I've added the '**if**' part to the script below, *which partly works*. It adds a class called 'NEW-CLASS' to the containing div (.figure-left).

Unfortunately it adds .NEW-CLASS to every div (.figure-left). It seems to ignore the 'if' bit? I only want a class adding to div (.figure-left) if there's a image inside with a class of .landscape

**HTML:**

```
<div class="figure-left">
<img alt="This is the caption" class="caption left landscape" 
height="413" src="/img/resources/photo.jpg"
width="620"><p class="caption">This is the caption</p>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("img.caption.left").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="figure-left"></div>')
    .after('<p class="caption">'+$(this).attr("title")+'</p>')
    .removeAttr('title');
    if ($('img').hasClass('landscape')) {
    $('.figure-left').addClass('NEW-CLASS');}
    });
```

*Really appreciate some help, been scratching my head all morning!* :)

I'm only using .NEW-CLASS for this example.

Comment: try: `if ($(this).hasClass('landscape')) {
        $(this).closest('.figure-left').addClass('NEW-CLASS');
    }`

Comment: HA! Bingo. Thanks A.Wolff :)

Comment: you are welcome Stephen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest skipping the `if` entirely, and selecting the relevant images (with the class-name you're testing for), and then finding the closest `.figure-left` and adding the class:

```
$('img.landscape').closest('.figure-left').addClass('NEW-CLASS');
```

However the problem with your own code was that you were selecting *all* the `.figure-left` elements inside of the `if`, so, instead, you should use:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('landscape')) {
    $(this).closest('.figure-left').addClass('NEW-CLASS');
}
```

In this example `$(this)` refers to the current element (the `img`) and tests whether it has the `landscape` class-name; if it *does* then the jQuery finds the closest `.figure-left` element of the ancestors of that `img` element and adds the `NEW-CLASS` class-name.

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

Comment: This feels cleaner. Both solutions work though. Thank you both for such quick and solid answers. Also thanks David for an explanation of the solution, I understand what I was doing wrong now.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! :)